# How to instantiate variable before the controllers are loaded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a simple AngularJS application. I am now trying to implement a L10n* mechanism into it. For that I have service which loads a strings file and returns an array of key-values. These values are later put into views and controllers.

To keep stuff straight and simple I assign the return array to **$rootScope** so that every controller/view has access to the same list.
I am doing it from the **angular.module(...).run()** function

And this is where the problem starts - some controllers can access the $rootScope object, whilst some other cant (and return undefined). I suspect this is because the promise is not resolved in time before the first few controllers are loaded.

*The question is - how do I make the controllers wait for the resource to be loaded?*

Auxiliary question - Why can *GenericListController* use $scope.localisation but *ListController* cant?

**service declaration**

```
app.factory("StringsTranslationService", function($http) {

    var getData = function(locale) {

        return $http({method:"GET", url:'public/resources/strings_'+locale+'.txt'}).then(function(result){
            return result.data[0];
        });
    };
    return { getData: getData };
});
```

load data from service to $rootScope in **app.js**

```
app.run(function($rootScope,StringsTranslationService) {
    var myDataPromise = StringsTranslationService.getData('en');
    myDataPromise.then(function(result) {
        $rootScope.localisation=result;
    });
});
```

Finally try to use in **controller.js**:

```
var app=angular.module('myApp');

app.controller('ListController', function ($scope, $controller){
    console.log($scope.localisation["_NAME_"]);
    angular.extend(this, $controller('GenericListController', {$scope: $scope}));
});
```

The most interesting fact is that *GenericListController* is also using the same $scope.localisation array and it has not problems with it!

The load order is:

1. app.js
2. service.js
3. genericController.js
4. controller.js

Comment: Have you considered storing your array of values in a factory object and injecting the dependency into your controllers rather than assigning the data to route scope?

Comment: Yes, Toby, I have but it's not a very efficient solution for me - please see my comment below to nitin's answer. In a nutshell - 1) I cant b/c my views sometimes dont have controllers, yet i use model variables there. 2) I got a bunch of controllers and I don't want to add extra code to each just to have support for async polling. I need the array to be loaded once and available all the time in the same fashion from $scope.localisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying yr results to $rootScope, you should directly read from service.

**why ?**
Yr $rootScope lives throughout yr application life, it sits right above all yr controller's scope, so its better to keep it lightest.

code :

```
app.factory("StringsTranslationService", function($http,$q) {

  var StringsTranslationService={};
  var data='';
  var dataReady=false;

  StringsTranslationService.getData = function (locale) {

    var deferred= $q.defer();
    $http({
      method:"GET",
      url:'public/resources/strings_'+locale+'.txt'
    })
    .success(function(result){
      deferred.resolve(result.data[0]);
    })
    .error(function(error){
      deferred.reject(error);
    })
    return deferred.promise;

 };

 return StringsTranslationService;
});
```

Update yr app.run

```
app.run(function(StringsTranslationService){

   //call service & read data
    StringsTranslationService.getData('en')
     .then(function(data){
          StringsTranslationService.data=data;
          StringsTranslationService.dataReady=true;

          //if you really want it add to rootScope
          //$rootScope.localisation=data;
      },
      function(error){
          //handle error here
      })  

});
```

Inside yr controller check if data is ready & then read

```
app.controller('ListController', function ($scope, StringsTranslationService){

    if(StringsTranslationService.dataReady===false){
      $scope.loading=true;
    }
    else {
       $scope.loading=false;
       $scope.data=StringsTranslationService.data;
    }


});
```

This way you will only do a single call to fetch data & it will b available across app.

Comment: I have considered this approach but it's not very viable for me for two reasons - I have a truckload of intertwined controllers (would need to update each) - and more importantly - some of my views (index.html) do not use a controller - so I need app-wide variables available there. Can't this be done anyway simpler? Also - why is it better not to use $rootScope (the impression I get from all over the Internet)

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find an exact solution to my problem.. Basically I needed to tell Angular - do "this" and ONLY when finished load controllers. Looks like that is impossible. Shame..
Anyways, I ended up implementing a similar solution to the one proposed above - a service and wrapping every of my controllers into a then directive (!). This produced a very ugly code. Moreover the resource was being loaded each time anew - more than 10 sequential reads of the same file. Good thing I found the {cache: true} option for the $http.get(). Thank you all!

Comment: Btw, this is not exactly the answer to my issue/question but i appreciate the effort and time. Thanks!